# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have installed SQL Server 2012 and I create procedure that searches freetext and it is working correctly. I using Visual Studio 2012 update 4.

But when I load the page in browser I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps full text search feature was not installed? or Have you created full text search catalog? if you have one, you will be able to find it under "Storage" in sql server management studio.

To install full text search feature - go to the link below

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/adding-sql-full-text-search-to-an-existing-sql-server/

Comment: yes I have created full text search catalog in Storage folder. the full-text search works well in SQL Server Management Studio but failed in Visual Web Developer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't installed Full-Text Search component of SQL Server or you did but service is not running.

Comment: I have installed in SQL Server and full-text search works well in SQL Server Management Studio but failed in Visual Web Developer